# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore could not be found error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

after i looked the tutorial in code project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30173/Restore-Database-during-Application-Deployment

i have already make referenced to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.dll and declare namespace

but the following code shows the error type or namespace name 'Restore' could not be found

```
        Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
        sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;
```

how to solve this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx) of the *Restore* class. You have to add the Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll assembly to your references.

Answer (score 0):

also make references to

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
```